# Why isn't my variable changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the following switch statement in order to change a global variable, but it will only change once.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" value =15>16x16</button>
<button type="button" value =31>32x32</button>
<button type="button" value =63>64x64</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 var initial_size = 15;
 var $cl;
 var $size;

 $(document).ready(function(){
   populate(initial_size);
 });

function populate(size){
   $('.main-table').empty();
   $size = size;
   switch($size){
    case 15:
        $cl = 'box';
        break;
    case 31:
         $cl = 'bigger-box';
         console.log("case 31");
        break;
    case 63:
         $cl = 'biggest-box';
         console.log("case 63");
         break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    console.log($cl);

    for(var i=0; i < $size; i++){
       $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
       for(var j=0; j < $size; j++){
           $div = $("<div class=" +$cl+"></div>");
           $div.css('background-color', 'lightslategrey');
           $tr.append($("<td></td>").append($div));
        }
       $(".main-table").append($tr);
     } 
   run();
};

 function run(){
     $('.box').hover(function(){
       $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
     });

     $('button').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
        populate($(this).val());
     });
  };
```

So when I run my code, $cl will be set to 'box', but whenever I click on another button and the loop runs again, $cl does not change to any of the other classes. Am I using the switch statement wrong, or am I not parsing the value correctly, or is the problem because I am using global variables? The only reason I am using global variables is because I am not too familiar with how scoping works in javascript yet, so I figured this way might be easier.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete, but from what you have posted you are not actually running the `run()` function to set up the event handlers. Also you have not closed your `run() function with a closing brace `}`

Comment: Try creating a fiddle on jsfiddle.net and link to the fiddle in your question.

Comment: nor have you closed you populate function. the last closing brace there relates to the switch statement

Comment: Syntax errors everywhere!! :O

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The run function is closed in my actual file, the bracket just got lost when I posted it

Comment: @DavePile the user has closed it, just has an extra parenthesis after the closing brace.

Comment: Scoping in JavaScript is easy. Every function has it's local scope. Variables declared in that scope with the `var` keyword are local to that function. The rest is global.

Comment: Maybe this jsfiddle can help. http://jsfiddle.net/j9m22ky8/2/

Comment: `function populate(size){
   $('.main-table').empty();
   $size = size;` doing this is a) pointless and b) bad style. There's no reason to assign `size` to `$size` (you shouldn't be using global variables). In addition, do not name your variables `$likeThis`. Snake case (`initial_size`) is also bad. Use camelCase: `initialSize`, `likeThis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I using the switch statement wrong, or am I not parsing the value correctly?

Exactly this. The values of your buttons are strings, but your `switch` statement is operating on numbers. `case` statements use strict equality which includes the type. So either parse your values to numbers, or use string literals in your cases. Currently, your code will always reach the `default` case.

> The only reason I am using global variables is because I am not too familiar with how scoping works in javascript yet, so I figured this way might be easier.

Quite simple actually: All function declarations, parameter declarations, and `var` declarations are scoped to the function that contains them. You really should be using local variables here.

Btw, you really should move that `run();` invocation from `populate` into the document-ready callback, next to `populate(initial_size);`. Currently, you are attaching a new set of event listeners every time you click a button, and all those listeners will fire on each click.